# install pil on virtualenv with libjpeg

Tags: django, python-imaging-library, virtualenv, pip

Currently I'm installing PIL into my virtual env as follows:

```
pip install -E . -r ./releases/%s/requirements.txt
```

where requirements.txt contains:

```
pil
```

I can upload png images but not jpeg images currently.  From reading on the web it seems i may need libjpeg decoder?  Am i installing pil incorrectly?  What is the proper way to install pil for django in a virtual env with libjpeg?

Comment: As far as I know, libjpeg needs to be installed in your libraries prior to installing pil. Good question however. If there's a better practice, I'd love to know.

Comment: What OS are you running? Find libjpeg in your package management system if that applies to you.  You'll probably want to uninstall PIL before you try re-installing so it will re-compile.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should install the libraries that others recommended but most importantly you should tell PIL where to find them. Edit the setup.py so that

```
    JPEG_ROOT = None
```

becomes

```
JPEG_ROOT = libinclude("/usr/lib")
```

I found that the easiest way was to download the source with pip but not install:

```
 pip install --no-install PIL
```

edit the setup (inside the build directory of the virtual environment) and the install

```
 pip install PIL
```

you can find some more information in my [blog](http://three99.com/posts/how-to-install-pil-on-ubuntu-with-jpeg-support)

You can also try [pillow](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/) which seems to do great job with little hassle (pip install pillow)

Comment: See also this Ubuntu thread http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1751455&page=2

Comment: Path in Ubuntu 12.04: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

Comment: Ran into the same problem with pillow (2.8.1). I had to do `pip install --no-install pillow`, and then replace the JPEG_ROOT line with `JPEG_ROOT = ("/path/to/libjpeg/lib", "/path/to/libjpeg/include")`. Finally install with `pip install /path/to/virtualenv/build/pillow` ---- Just in case someone (including myself) needs this in the future

Answer (score 10):

On Ubuntu precise, PIL doesn't find the jpeg library files, even once they are installed. The easiest way to  fix this is to make a symlink after you have installed the jpeg dev package.
So, I needed an extra step:

```
pip uninstall PIL
sudo apt-get install libjpeg8-dev
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so /usr/lib
pip install PIL
```

Comment: `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so /usr/lib`
did the job for me

Comment: more generic: `ln -sf /usr/lib/\`uname -i\`-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so /usr/lib/` uname detects your machines infrastructure automatically.

Answer (score 8):

For Ubuntu 11.04, what finally worked for me is:

```
pip uninstall PIL
sudo apt-get install libjpeg8-dev
pip install PIL
```

The Python Imaging Library (PIL) seems really picky about version and location of the jpeg libraries.  And because PIL is written in C and compiled, you need the ***development*** versions of the library in addition to the runtime versions.

The situation is so bad the community forked PIL to create a softer version: Pillow:
    http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow#why-a-fork

Answer (score 6):

On OSX, I used the following binary to get libpng and libjpeg simultaneously installed systemwide:

[libpng & libjpeg for OSX](http://ethan.tira-thompson.com/Mac_OS_X_Ports.html)

Because I already had PIL installed (via pip on a virtualenv), I ran:

```
pip uninstall PIL
pip install PIL --upgrade
```

This resolved the `decoder JPEG not available` error for me.

Comment: many, many thanks! The key bit for me was the binary, because I tried installing libjpeg using `brew`, but that didn't work for me, while this nailed it (OSX 10.8.3).

Answer (score 3):

You must install the libraries:

```
sudo aptitude install libjpeg62 libjpeg62-dev zlib1g-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

if pip raises an error, try
    easy_install PIL