# PIL /JPEG Library: "decoder jpeg not available"

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library, redhat, libjpeg

I tried to use PIL to do some JPEG work in my django app with PIL but I'm getting this IOError.. not sure what to do.

```
""decoder jpeg not available""
```

Am I missing the JPEG decoder from my server? If so, how do I fix it?

Comment: I found this post and it really helps me : http://obroll.com/install-python-pil-python-image-library-on-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Image Library fails with message "decoder JPEG not available PIL"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915296/python-image-library-fails-with-message-decoder-jpeg-not-available-pil)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You need to install jpeg library first and reinstall your PIL.  For example, I'm using CentOS, to install libjpeg, I run

```
sudo yum install -y libjpeg-devel
```

It depends on what kind of linux you are using. And here you have to remove the old PIL

```
rm -rf /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PIL-1.1.7-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/
```

Then install the PIL

```
sudo easy_install PIL
```

Answer (score 73):

*I have found this answer from author "edward"*

On Ubuntu precise, PIL doesn't find the jpeg library files, even once they are installed. The easiest way to fix this is to make a symlink after you have installed the jpeg dev package. So, I needed an extra step:

**for x64 OS**

```
pip uninstall PIL
sudo apt-get install libjpeg8-dev
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so /usr/lib
pip install PIL
```

**for x32 OS**

```
pip uninstall PIL
sudo apt-get install libjpeg8-dev
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so /usr/lib
pip install PIL
```

**I confirm that this is working for me on Ubuntu Linux 12.04.**

---

If you are a **Mac** user - you need to install Xcode and Command Line Tools. [Read how to do this](http://python-on-mac.blogspot.com/2013/02/prepare-your-mac-to-work-in-python.html)

Comment: `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so /usr/lib` did the job for me

Comment: Nathan Keller, it depends on your system version. x64 or x32. Thank you. I have edited my answer.

Comment: I have found solution for Mac users here: http://python-on-mac.blogspot.com/2013/02/prepare-your-mac-to-work-in-python.html

Comment: Mac users do NOT need to install all of XCode to write a simple jpeg file with PIL. Simply run `brew install libjpeg` and reinstall PIL as prescribed above and you will be up and running.

Answer (score 20):

A stronger answer can be found at [install pil on virtualenv with libjpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435016/install-pil-on-virtualenv-with-libjpeg)

For me what finally worked on Ubutu was:

```
pip uninstall PIL
sudo apt-get install libjpeg8-dev
pip install PIL
```

The Python Imaging Library (PIL) seems really picky about version and location of the jpeg libraries.  And because PIL is written in C and compiled, you need the ***development*** versions of the library in addition to the runtime versions.

Comment: At Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS using Pillow
`pip uninstall Pillow`
`sudo apt-get install libjpeg8-dev`
`pip install Pillow`
 works for me

Answer (score 6):

I don't have sudo privileges, because I am on a shared bluehost server. So I can't run any of those sudo apt-get jpeg commands. I ended up running

```
pip uninstall pil
pip install pillow
```

and apparently pillow was able to find support for jpegs.

Comment: Actually I still have:  `IOError: decoder jpeg not available` after doing this.

Comment: A combination of @cmaluenda's answer below and this one worked.

Comment: Yeah, but if you are running a mac server you are going to have a million more problems before you get this one.

Answer (score 4):

There is a selftest.py in your Imaging installation folder, try:

```
python selftest.py
```

you will see something like that:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
*** PIL CORE support not installed
*** TKINTER support not installed
--- JPEG support ok
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support ok
*** FREETYPE2 support not installed
*** LITTLECMS support not installed
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

if JPEG support not available, Centos:

```
yum install libjpeg-devel
yum install freetype-devel 
yum install libpng-devel
```

Answer (score 3):

For mac's users, You can download the library from here: http://ethan.tira-thompson.com/Mac_OS_X_Ports.html. Then, uninstall and install PIL

Comment: anyway to use brew instead of macports?

Answer (score 0):

You can build PIL from source: http://effbot.org/zone/pil-decoder-jpeg-not-available.htm

Comment: I did, but running the selftest it still tells me ..



from line #24 of selftest.testimage
Expected: ('JPEG', 'RGB', (128, 128))
Got: decoder jpeg not available
1 items had failures:
   1 of  57 in selftest.testimage
***Test Failed*** 1 failures.
*** 1 tests of 57 failed.

Comment: I'm assuming the whole ./configure --with-jpeg=/somelib/lib --with-zlib=/somelib/lib line means I need to go fetch a copt of the jpeg library

Comment: Yes, but you can probably do that with your package manager, e.g. on Ubuntu: "apt-get install libjpeg-dev".

Answer (score 0):

On Debian distributions use libjpeg62-turbo-dev instead of libjpeg8-dev