# sorl-thumbnail: Creating a thumbnail inside a for loop in a template

Tags: django, sorl-thumbnail

I am trying to create a thumbnail with the size of `100x100 px` from an image. I am using a for loop, and the for loops works and the image is rendered but for some reason when I am trying to create a thumbnail it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
{% for post_images in post.sellpostimage_set.all %}
           <img class="thumbnail" src="{{ post_images.pictures.url }}" />

            {% thumbnail post_images "100x100" crop="center" as im %}
                <img src="{{ im.pictures.url }}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}">
            {% endthumbnail %}

{% endfor %}
```

`views.py`

```
def post(request, post_name_slug):
    context_dict = {}
    try:

        post = SellPost.objects.get(slug=post_name_slug)
        context_dict['post'] = post

        poster_posts = SellPost.objects.filter(user=post.user).order_by('-timestamp')
        context_dict['poster_posts'] = poster_posts

        post_image = SellPostImage.objects.filter(post=poster_posts)
        context_dict['post_image'] = post_image

        poster = post.user
        context_dict['poster'] = poster

    except SellPost.DoesNotExist:
        return redirect('index')
    return render(request, 'post.html', context_dict, )
```

EDIT: If I use in the thumbnail src {{ im.url }} I can get the Image location which is weird..
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/cache/9b/0b/9b0b04d65b1075ed4c3e7783131caef6.jpg` , but again the thumbnail image is still not being rendered. Shows as the URL is broken, and when I try to go to the image location url I get a 404 error.

Comment: Please show `post_images` definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your plural are in the wrong spot:

```
{% for post_images in post.sellpostimage_set.all %}
```

should be:

```
{% for post_image in post.sellpostimage_set.all %}
```

---

```
post_image = SellPostImage.objects.filter(post=poster_posts)
context_dict['post_image'] = post_image
```

should be:

```
post_images = SellPostImage.objects.filter(post=poster_posts)
context_dict['post_images'] = post_images
```

or:

```
post_image = SellPostImage.objects.get(post=poster_posts)
context_dict['post_image'] = post_image
```

---

why do you do this in your template:

```
{% for post_images in post.sellpostimage_set.all %}
```

if you have `post_images` in the context?

---

How does this work?

```
<img class="thumbnail" src="{{ post_images.pictures.url }}" />
```

shouldn't it be:

```
<img class="thumbnail" src="{{ post_image.picture.url }}" />
```

Comment: Okay fixed everything now, but now when I try to get the pictures_thumbnail it gives me a `Exception Value: decoder jpeg not available` I have Pillow installed instead of PIL is that the problem, any idea?

Comment: Well that a different issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555831/decoder-jpeg-not-available-error-when-following-django-photo-app-tutorial