# apt-get package in virtualenv

Tags: virtualenv, apt-get, linux-mint

Hi i am trying to install python imaging library in a virtual environment in linuxmint 17.1. 
I tried this link.
[Decoder JPEG not available error when following Django photo app tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555831/decoder-jpeg-not-available-error-when-following-django-photo-app-tutorial)

I also posted this question but no answer till now.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31473765/install-libjpeg-dev-in-virtualenv-ubuntu

EDIT:

I am installing [Shoop](http://shoop.io) in my linuxmint system in a virtualenv. This program requires both Pillow and PIL to be installed in a virtualenv. I installed Pillow and PIL in virtual environment but it also requires following libraries to be installed in virtualenv.

- libjpeg-dev
- libpng12-dev
- zlib1g-dev

I installed these libraries via apt-get.

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev zlib1g-dev libpng12-dev
```

Since apt-get installs packages system wide. How to use them in my virtualenv.

Also if there is a way to separately install them in virtualenv.

Comment: virtualenv is a tool to create isolated **Python** environments, you can't install other things like your system packages inside it. If you're having difficulties to install PIL, try Pillow instead, which is a pip-installable fork of PIL. When asking a question, try to describe the original problem you experienced, not your attempted solution (see [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

Comment: I hope the edit will do. I wrote the complete problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say no.

Everything you install through apt-get is OS related.

As [Audrius Kažukauskas commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31509555/apt-get-package-in-virtualenv#comment50982081_31509555) and [Virtualenv documentation](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/index.html#what-it-does) docs states:

> virtualenv is a tool to **create isolated Python environments**.
>
> The basic problem being addressed is one of dependencies and versions,
>   and indirectly permissions.

Comment: I know apt-get installs package system wide. In my case there is a python imaging library PILLOW which i can install in my virtualenv. But the open source program i am working on also require above 3 libraries alongwith pillow. That's why i am unable to progress further.

Comment: right, my answer is because since it's system wide, they do not fit into virtualenv scope and at least should be specified on project docs they versions and/or how to install