# PIL installed but images are still not saving

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I am working on a Django project & I am new to Python. Now I have to set up my amazon server (ubuntu) for running Django Project. I installed all the necessary Package and my project is running on the server but here comes the main problem. I want to store images on the server, for that I required to install `PIL` which is I think used for handling image file. I installed PIL, some dependencies problem were coming i resoled that and the output of installing `PIL` is given below:

```
sudo pip install PIL
Downloading/unpacking PIL
Running setup.py egg_info for package PIL
WARNING: '' not a valid package name; please use only.-separated package names in setup.py

Installing collected packages: PIL
Running setup.py install for PIL
WARNING: '' not a valid package name; please use only.-separated package names in setup.py
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PIL 1.1.7 SETUP SUMMARY
--------------------------------------------------------------------
version       1.1.7
platform      linux2 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2013, 05:46:21)
              [GCC 4.6.3]
--------------------------------------------------------------------
--- TKINTER support available
--- JPEG support available
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support available
--- FREETYPE2 support available
*** LITTLECMS support not available
--------------------------------------------------------------------
To add a missing option, make sure you have the required
library, and set the corresponding ROOT variable in the
setup.py script.

To check the build, run the selftest.py script.

changing mode of /usr/local/bin/pilfile.py to 755
changing mode of /usr/local/bin/pilfont.py to 755
changing mode of /usr/local/bin/pildriver.py to 755
changing mode of /usr/local/bin/pilconvert.py to 755
changing mode of /usr/local/bin/pilprint.py to 755
Successfully installed PIL
Cleaning up...
```

I also created a symbolic link of the following files:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so /usr/lib
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so /usr/lib
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so /usr/lib
```

But still I am not able to store the images on the server. A error is coming saying `'decoder jpeg not available'`. now I am confused. please help me to escape from this problem. I have also installed pillow but still no success.

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment?

Comment: No I am simply using the default python installation directory ie. /usr/local/lib/python 2.7

Comment: The lines about `libz.so` in your question are duplicated, is there `libjpeg` link?

Comment: Ohh sorry I updated my question.

Comment: one more thing I want to add is that my server's PIL directory is missing _imagingcms.so file. I dont know why.

Comment: [This could help you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10109941/1628832)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether I am correct or not but some one has written in his blog that one should be careful while using sudo command with pip. I was using the sudo command with pip for installing PIL i.e I was running `sudo pip install PIL`. This command installed PIL. But it was not working for me.

Then I simply run `pip install PIL`, it gives me some permission error like `access denied'. I resolved those permission problem and find out that now images are storing properly on the server and I didn't get any error further. I don't know why but it worked for me. Thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have only one libjpeg version installed:

```
lsof | grep libjpeg
```

It turned out to be exactly my case.