# PIL decoder jpeg not available on ubuntu x64,

Tags: python, jpeg, python-imaging-library

I know that this question looks like a duplicate but I've followed many online instructions on how to properly install PIL and none have worked.

I've tried everything in: [Python Image Library fails with message "decoder JPEG not available" - PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915296/decoder-jpeg-not-available-pil) with no success.

When I run sudo pip install pil, worst of all, there is a misleading error. Jpeg, Freetyle, etc support is all listed as available. But when running some python code using PIL, the
notorious IOError of "decoder jpeg not available' comes up.

Even after symlinking into /usr/lib for the .so libjpeg files, nothing has worked.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can try this:

**1. clear PIL packages**

```
rm -rf /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL
rm -rf /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL.pth
```

**2. install required packages**

```
ubuntu:
apt-get install libjpeg-dev libfreetype6-dev zlib1g-dev libpng12-dev

centos:
yum install zlib zlib-devel
yum install libjpeg libjpeg-devel
yum install freetype freetype-devel
```

**3.download Image and install**

```
wget http://effbot.org/downloads/Imaging-1.1.7.tar.gz
tar xzvf Imaging-1.1.7.tar.gz
cd Imaging-1.1.7
# if the sys is x64, you must also do this: edit the setup.py file and set:
# centOS:
TCL_ROOT = '/usr/lib64'
JPEG_ROOT = '/usr/lib64'
ZLIB_ROOT = '/usr/lib64'
TIFF_ROOT = '/usr/lib64'
FREETYPE_ROOT = '/usr/lib64'
LCMS_ROOT = '/usr/lib64'
# Ubuntu:
TCL_ROOT = '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu'
JPEG_ROOT = '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu'
ZLIB_ROOT = '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu'
TIFF_ROOT = '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu'
FREETYPE_ROOT = '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu'
LCMS_ROOT = '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu'
#then install it use:
python2.7 setup.py install
```

**4. check if it works**

```
# before this command you should run `mv PIL PIL2`

python2.7 selftest.py
```

If the result is:

```
--- PIL CORE support ok
--- TKINTER support ok
--- JPEG support ok
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support ok
--- FREETYPE2 support ok
*** LITTLECMS support not installed
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Running selftest:
--- 57 tests passed.
```

Congratulation!!

Comment: I'm try solution but ` ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing module ` "No module named PIL"

Comment: use `import Image` replace `from PIL import Image`

Comment: having same error .. then i followed yours . test is passed but throwing below error `.. Exception Location: build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/PIL/Image.py in _getdecoder, line 415`

Comment: Failure in example: len(im.tostring())
from line #76 of selftest.testimage
Exception raised:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./doctest.py", line 499, in _run_examples_inner
    exec compile(source, "<string>", "single") in globs
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 697, in tostring
    "Please call tobytes() instead.")
NotImplementedError: tostring() has been removed. Please call tobytes() instead.

Comment: 1 items had failures:
   1 of  57 in selftest.testimage
***Test Failed*** 1 failures.
*** 1 tests of 57 failed.