# IOError: decoder jpeg not available

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Everybody

I have done a lot of search about my question, some similar questions below:

1. [IOError: decoder jpeg not available when using Pillow 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24089880/ioerror-decoder-jpeg-not-available-when-using-pillow)
2. [PIL decoder jpeg not available on ubuntu x64, 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504835/pil-decoder-jpeg-not-available-on-ubuntu-x64)

but problem still remains.

---

Problem Description:

- Installing Python PIL in my MacOS X 10.9.5
- I did install the following plugins:

> PIL CORE,TKINTER,JPEG,ZLIB,FREETYPE2

As you can see the selftest result below:
[image]

---

But Exception remains, here's the detail:
[image]

Any effort will be truely appreciated.

Comment: I gave up and installed anaconda.

Comment: What about [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915296/python-image-library-fails-with-message-decoder-jpeg-not-available-pil) [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632261/pil-jpeg-library-help)?

Comment: @PeterWood These answer are for Linux. Try the following : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404956/installing-pil-with-jpeg-support-on-mac-os-x

Answer (score 1):

I got it solved by installing PILLOW instead of PIL, and it works for me.

> sudo rm -r /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL
>
> pip install pillow

But I don't know why.