# Django PIL - how to install to system site-packages?

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-imaging-library

I want to use the ImageField in Django and I was told to install Pillow rather than PIL. I installed Pillow by doing this

```
pip install Pillow
```

and then when I ran the server, it said

```
To use ImageFields, you need to install PIL
```

but I was told it should work with just having Pillow. I did further research and I read that I should try

```
pip install Pillow-PIL
```

and I tried that and it still have the same error. I tried import it in models.py like this:

```
from PIL import Image
```

but then it gave an error saying 'No module named PIL'. What am I doing wrong? On another SO post, a user said

```
Did you install Pillow into your system site-packages? or into a virtualenv's site-packages?
```

How do I confirm that Pillow is installed into my system site-packages?

Note: I am using Django 1.5, Python 2.7 and not using virtualenv.

Comment: Did you try just importing `Image`?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams yup, it says 'No module named Image'

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: @Foon I am using Lubuntu (Linux)

Comment: @Totem what do you mean by 'import it properly'? What else am I supposed to do other than the pip install and typing 'from PIL import Image' in my models.py file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django - PIL / Pillow not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21948510/django-pil-pillow-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

First to check whether any package is installed use:

```
pip freeze
```

libjpeg-dev is required for PIL to process jpeg format.
Use the following link for any other PIL errors:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10109941/2323987

Comment: Also make sure you activated the venv in which you installed the package.

Comment: okay I did pip freeze and I have edited my post to show what came up. There is no Pillow or PIL, how come? And how do I 'activate the venv which I installed the package in'? I've never used venv before, I just did the 'pip install' commands in the 'downloads' directory. Do I need to syncdb again after doing the pip installations?

Comment: Did you activate the virtual env before doing pip freeze? Command: source venvname/bin/activate

Comment: I don't have a venv, I wouldn't know what my 'venvname' is.. is there a way for me to 'create' one? I started working on the project and never did anything regarding venv before so i'm not too sure how it's done. How do I get the venv name?

Comment: @Trickster whoops sorry, I was posting with a different account but user2817200 is me. I just realized I'm signed in with a different account on my host OS, I normally post using my VM but the last two posts were from the host OS and I wasn't aware that it was a different account. Anyways, how do I create a venv / find out the venv name?

Comment: I suggest you to read about python virtual environments . It will be very useful in future. So, for try reinstalling it...command for uninstall: pip uninstall package. Follow the link I gave in the answer while reinstalling.