# Problems downloading PIL library

Tags: python, download, python-imaging-library

I've been scourging the internet, trying all sorts of solutions in regards to downloading the PIL library, but nothing seems to work for me. I keep getting the error:

raise IOError("decoder %s not available" % decoder_name)
IOError: decoder jpeg not available

Currently using mavericks. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this Q/A answers your question

[Python Image Library fails with message "decoder JPEG not available" - PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915296/python-image-library-fails-with-message-decoder-jpeg-not-available-pil)

quick summation. Try uninstalling PIL and installing https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.1.0

Comment: Yep, Pillow is the way to go.