# "decoder jpeg not available" with Pillow on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, python-imaging-library

i'm having some trouble to handle jpeg files on Python under AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

I have this on .ebextensions/python.config file:

```
packages:
 yum:
  libjpeg-turbo-devel: []
  libpng-devel: []
  freetype-devel: []
...
```

So i believe i have libjpeg installed and working (i tried libjpeg-devel, but yum can't find this package).

Also, i have this on my requirements.txt:

```
Pillow==2.5.1
...
```

So i believe i have Pillow installed and working on my environment.

Then, since i have Pillow and libjpeg, i'm trying to do some work using PIL.Image in a Python script and save to a file. Like this:

```
from PIL import Image

def resize_image(image,new_size,crop=False,correctOrientationSize=False):
  assert type(new_size) == dict
  assert new_size.has_key('width') and new_size.has_key('height')

  THUM_SIZE = [new_size['width'],new_size['height']]

  file_like = cStringIO.StringIO(base64.decodestring(image))
  thumbnail = Image.open(file_like)

  (width,height) = thumbnail.size
  if correctOrientationSize and height > width:
    THUM_SIZE.reverse()

  thumbnail.thumbnail(THUM_SIZE)

  if crop:
    # Recorta imagem
    thumbnail = crop_image(thumbnail)
  output = cStringIO.StringIO()
  thumbnail.save(output,format='jpeg')

return output.getvalue().encode('base64')
```

However, when i try to run it on Elastic Beanstalk's instance, the exception "decoder jpeg not available" when it calls .save() method.

If i SSH into my instance, it works just fine and i already tried to rebuild the environment.

What am i doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

As suggested, i SSHed again into the instance and reinstalled Pillow through pip (/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip), not before i has had sure libjpeg-devel was on environment before Pillow.

I ran selftest.py and it confirmed that i had support for jpeg. So, in a last try, i went to "Restart App Server" on Elastic Beanstalk interface. It worked.

Thank you all.

Comment: Did you install libjpeg before or after Pillow?

Comment: @IanAuld I don't have sure what order EB follows. I just add this requirements and EB installs. Is the order important?

Comment: I'm my experience libjpeg has to be present when pillow is installed. Try uninstalling pillow and installing it again once you are sure libjpeg is installed.

Comment: packages are installed before processing requirements.txt. Can you snapshot your logs to see if any errors that show up in the logs?
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.loggingS3.title.html

Comment: I SSHed again into the instance and reinstalled Pillow through pip (/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip) . I ran selftest.py and it confirmed that i had support for jpeg. So, in a last try, i went to "Restart App Server" on Elastic Beanstalk interface. It worked. Thank you all.

Comment: @PedroAlves: Please can you add your answer in the answer box below? That way this doesn't show up as unanswered and others can find the solution quicker.

Comment: @Hugo Sure. It's done.

Answer (score 8):

Following the general advice from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915296/python-image-library-fails-with-message-decoder-jpeg-not-available-pil?rq=1), I solved this by adding the following in my .ebextensions configuration and re-deploying.

```
packages:
  yum:
    libjpeg-turbo-devel: []
    libpng-devel: []
    freetype-devel: []

container_commands:
...
  05_uninstall_pil:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && yes | pip uninstall Pillow"

  06_reinstall_pil:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && yes | pip install Pillow --no-cache-dir"
```

Answer (score 3):

As suggested, I SSHed again into the instance and reinstalled Pillow through pip (/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip), not before I has had sure libjpeg-devel was on environment before Pillow.

I ran selftest.py and it confirmed that I had support for jpeg. So, in a last try, I went to "Restart App Server" on Elastic Beanstalk interface. It worked.