# 'IOError decoder not available' when uploading picture

Tags: django, python-imaging-library

I am using userena, and I'm guessing I don't have the correct encoder installed (which I'm guessing is pil?)  The error below appears whenever I try to upload a profile pic.  How do I resolve this?

```
IOError at /accounts/billy/edit/

decoder jpeg not available

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/billy/edit/
Django Version:     1.6
Exception Type:     IOError
Exception Value:    

decoder jpeg not available

Exception Location: /home/ben/Documents/proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages      /PIL/Image.py in _getdecoder
```

Comment: This should have what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915296/python-image-library-fails-with-message-decoder-jpeg-not-available-pil

Comment: I have pillow installed for this project.  shouldn't django be using pillow instead of pil?