# Python OSError decoder jpeg not available. No solutions working

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-imaging-library

I got this error "OSError decoder jpeg not available" when using pillow. I tried everything I found on google but nothing worked. 
I'm using python 3 on ubuntu 14.04. pip version 7.0.3, Pillow version 2.8.2.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Image Library fails with message "decoder JPEG not available" - PIL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915296/python-image-library-fails-with-message-decoder-jpeg-not-available-pil)

Comment: Can you add a code example where it goes wrong?

Answer (score 0):

A little late to this, but it might help someone else…

I would suggest following the [Rolo's directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915296/python-image-library-fails-with-message-decoder-jpeg-not-available-pil) . If that fails, one additional thing to try is [rouxxx's tip](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/1275), which is to clear your local `pip` cache (e.g., `rm -rf ~/.cache/pip`) and see if that helps.