# Error while installing Pillow --enable-jpeg requested but jpeg not found

Tags: python, pip, python-imaging-library

I get this error while installing Pillow, the python imaging library.

```
> pip intall pillow
...
--enable-jpeg requested but jpeg not found
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is at

[Python Image Library fails with message "decoder JPEG not available" - PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915296/python-image-library-fails-with-message-decoder-jpeg-not-available-pil)

I needed to install the jpeg developer library.

```
> sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev
```

That solved the problem.

Comment: How about closing this as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915296/python-image-library-fails-with-message-decoder-jpeg-not-available-pil?

Comment: I could not find the question when I tried searching with the error string and pillow but it is indeed a duplicate. How do I close it so that it still shows up in search results.

Comment: Closing as a duplicate keeps the question here, so people can still find this via search results and then go to the original.