# Python Image Library fails with message “IOError: decoder jpeg not available” - PIL when compile in SageMath Notebook

Tags: python-2.7, image-processing, jpeg, sage

I'm facing an strange problem with PIL. Whenever I am compiling the following code with python everything is ok:

```
from PIL import Image
file=Image.open("si.jpg") 
file2=file.convert("L")
pix = file2.load()
print pix
colsize,rowsize=file2.size
for i in range(rowsize):
    for j in range(colsize): 
        if pix[j,i]>250:
            pix[j,i]=250
file2.save("ci2.pgm")
```

But when I compile the above code in SageMath Notebook, it gives an error  ***“IOError: decoder jpeg not available”***. Here is the scrrenshot :
[image]
I have found a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915296/python-image-library-fails-with-message-decoder-jpeg-not-available-pil), but these solution does not work for me. My OS is Ubuntu 16.04 (32bit).
The  image link :[image])
I want to get solution for SageMath. How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It seems your version of the Python package "Pillow"
(the Python Image Library) is missing the decoder for jpg.

To install it, quit Sage, and in a terminal, run the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev
$ sage --pip install --no-cache-dir -I pillow
```

Then restart Sage and try running your code again.

Comment: Note that if you run `sage -f pillow`, then jpg support will not be compiled, because it is disabled in the Sage installation file for pillow. Using `sage --pip install ... pillow` should work, though.