# Troubles with PIL on Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pygame, python-imaging-library

When I tried to run some .py file on my Ubuntu-12* (it is emulated via VirtualBox) I got the message:

```
raise IOError("decoder %s not available" % decoder_name)
IOError: decoder jpeg not available
```

After looking for answers I have found some potential recipes for solving this problem here: [PIL /JPEG Library / Help!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632261/pil-jpeg-library-help) and in particular (as I suppose) here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12301138/1522479
...where was said following:

```
On Ubuntu precise, PIL doesn't find the jpeg library files, even once they are installed. The easiest way to fix this is to make a symlink after you have installed the jpeg dev package. So, I needed an extra step:

for x64 OS

pip uninstall PIL
sudo apt-get install libjpeg8-dev
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so /usr/lib
pip install PIL
```

However when I tried this solution, I haven't got the desired result.
Here the end of log (sorry for such a huge piece):

```
PIL 1.1.7 SETUP SUMMARY
--------------------------------------------------------------------    
version       1.1.7

platform      linux2 2.7.4 (default, Apr 19 2013, 18:28:01)

              [GCC 4.7.3]    
--------------------------------------------------------------------    
*** TKINTER support not available (Tcl/Tk 8.5 libraries needed)    
--- JPEG support available    
*** ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support not available    
*** FREETYPE2 support not available    
*** LITTLECMS support not available    
--------------------------------------------------------------------

To add a missing option, make sure you have the required    
library, and set the corresponding ROOT variable in the    
setup.py script.

To check the build, run the selftest.py script.    
running build_scripts    
creating build/scripts-2.7    
copying and adjusting Scripts/pilfile.py -> build/scripts-2.7    
copying and adjusting Scripts/pildriver.py -> build/scripts-2.7    
copying and adjusting Scripts/pilconvert.py -> build/scripts-2.7    
copying Scripts/pilfont.py -> build/scripts-2.7    
copying and adjusting Scripts/pilprint.py -> build/scripts-2.7    
changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/pilfile.py from 664 to 775    
changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/pildriver.py from 664 to 775    
changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/pilconvert.py from 664 to 775    
changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/pilfont.py from 664 to 775    
changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/pilprint.py from 664 to 775    
running install_lib    
creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL



error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL': Permission denied


----------------------------------------
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-nupic/PIL/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-p6ZHoT-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-nupic/PIL
Storing complete log in /home/nupic/.pip/pip.log 
nupic@nupic-vm:/$
```

---

The another issue is that I didn't use linux (I literally forced to start doing it couples of month ago), so I have no idea how to manage this situation. I need help, really.
P.S. If it matters - before I tried run .py file I had installed pygame (successfully).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL': Permission denied
```

suggests that you have a permissions problem, if you really want to install PIL system wide, use:

```
sudo pip install PIL
```

you can also install to a user-owned directory:

```
sudo pip install --install-option="--prefix=$PREFIX_PATH" PIL
```

or, preferably, install within a virtualenv,

Comment: Chris, your solution works. Thank you SO much! Just amazing how easy it looks - I spent literally 2 (two!) minutes to get desired result. :)

Answer (score 0):

you could try installing pillow instead which is fork of PIL.
I use it for all my sites that need PIL.

to install pip install pillow

see https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow