# Install PIL works for sudo, can't use in venv

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, ubuntu-10.04

I'm working in Ubuntu 10.04. The default python on my machine is 2.6. I created a virutalenv with python 2.7. I am writing a django app to be run on googleappengine. In order to use an ImageField in one of my models I need to install PIL. There are many, many posts about installing PIL, and I have followed many of them with no success.

I am able to successfuly run

```
sudo pip install PIL
```

but my virtualenv cannot access it. When I run

```
pip install PIL
```

inside my virtualenv I get a gcc error.

I installed all the dependencies, apt-get installed python-imaging, downloaded PIL and tried to build/install with setup.py and followed many other instructions in the many posts I've read.

Does anyone have any ideas?

EDIT:

The error:

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

EDIT: AS MUCH OF THE ERROR AS I CAN PASTE (THE REST IS OFF THE SCREEN)

```
 _imaging.c:301: error: ‘PyExc_IOError’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

_imaging.c:302: error: ‘NULL’ undeclared (first use in this function)

_imaging.c: In function ‘ImagingError_MemoryError’:

_imaging.c:308: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘PyErr_NoMemory’

_imaging.c:308: warning: return makes pointer from integer without a cast

_imaging.c: In function ‘ImagingError_Mismatch’:

_imaging.c:314: error: ‘PyExc_ValueError’ undeclared (first use in this function)

_imaging.c:315: error: ‘NULL’ undeclared (first use in this function)

_imaging.c: In function ‘ImagingError_ModeError’:

_imaging.c:321: error: ‘PyExc_ValueError’ undeclared (first use in this function)

_imaging.c:322: error: ‘NULL’ undeclared (first use in this function)

_imaging.c: In function ‘ImagingError_ValueError’:

_imaging.c:329: error: ‘PyExc_ValueError’ undeclared (first use in this function)

_imaging.c:332: error: ‘NULL’ undeclared (first use in this function)

_imaging.c: In function ‘ImagingError_Clear’:

_imaging.c:338: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘PyErr_Clear’

_imaging.c: At top level:

_imaging.c:369: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:464: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:510: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:587: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:619: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:631: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:643: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:655: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:664: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:675: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:686: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:697: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:719: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:743: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:760: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:777: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:786: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:803: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:813: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:824: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:857: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:879: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:914: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:954: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:981: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:1054: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:1065: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:1075: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:1114: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:1191: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:1202: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:1339: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:1359: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:1394: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:1419: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:1448: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:1459: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:1479: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:1530: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:1568: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:1614: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:1689: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:1739: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:1765: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:1771: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:1783: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:1817: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:1845: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:1874: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:1885: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:1901: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:1922: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:1928: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:1939: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:1950: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:1961: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:1972: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:1983: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:2001: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:2019: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:2030: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:2041: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:2052: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:2063: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:2081: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c: In function ‘_font_dealloc’:

_imaging.c:2142: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘Py_XDECREF’

_imaging.c:2142: error: ‘ImagingFontObject’ has no member named ‘ref’

_imaging.c: In function ‘textwidth’:

_imaging.c:2152: error: ‘ImagingFontObject’ has no member named ‘glyphs’

_imaging.c: At top level:

_imaging.c:2157: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:2205: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:2215: error: array type has incomplete element type

_imaging.c:2216: error: ‘PyCFunction’ undeclared here (not in a function)

_imaging.c:2216: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_font_getmask’

_imaging.c:2217: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_font_getsize’

_imaging.c:2218: error: ‘NULL’ undeclared here (not in a function)

_imaging.c:2221: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:2229: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c: In function ‘_draw_dealloc’:

_imaging.c:2257: error: ‘ImagingDrawObject’ has no member named ‘image’

_imaging.c: At top level:

_imaging.c:2261: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:2263: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:2278: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:2298: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:2335: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:2353: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:2390: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:2406: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:2459: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:2474: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:2507: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:2509: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:2536: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:2554: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:2600: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:2637: error: array type has incomplete element type

_imaging.c:2640: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_draw_line’

_imaging.c:2641: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_draw_lines’

_imaging.c:2643: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_draw_outline’

_imaging.c:2645: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_draw_polygon’

_imaging.c:2646: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_draw_rectangle’

_imaging.c:2647: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_draw_point’

_imaging.c:2648: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_draw_points’

_imaging.c:2649: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_draw_arc’

_imaging.c:2650: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_draw_bitmap’

_imaging.c:2651: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_draw_chord’

_imaging.c:2652: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_draw_ellipse’

_imaging.c:2653: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_draw_pieslice’

_imaging.c:2654: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_draw_ink’

_imaging.c:2659: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:2668: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c: In function ‘pixel_access_dealloc’:

_imaging.c:2693: error: ‘PixelAccessObject’ has no member named ‘image’

_imaging.c: At top level:

_imaging.c:2697: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:2708: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘PyObject’

_imaging.c:2708: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘PyObject’

_imaging.c: In function ‘pixel_access_setitem’:

_imaging.c:2710: error: ‘PixelAccessObject’ has no member named ‘image’

_imaging.c:2714: error: ‘PixelAccessObject’ has no member named ‘readonly’

_imaging.c:2719: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘_getxy’

_imaging.c:2719: error: ‘xy’ undeclared (first use in this function)

_imaging.c:2723: error: ‘PyExc_IndexError’ undeclared (first use in this function)

_imaging.c:2727: error: ‘color’ undeclared (first use in this function)

_imaging.c:2730: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘getink’

_imaging.c:2733: error: ‘PixelAccessObject’ has no member named ‘image’

_imaging.c: At top level:

_imaging.c:2744: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:2763: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:2774: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:2791: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:2811: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:2846: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:2867: error: array type has incomplete element type

_imaging.c:2870: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_getpixel’

_imaging.c:2871: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_putpixel’

_imaging.c:2873: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘pixel_access_new’

_imaging.c:2876: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_convert’

_imaging.c:2877: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_convert2’

_imaging.c:2878: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_convert_matrix’

_imaging.c:2879: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_copy’

_imaging.c:2880: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_copy2’

_imaging.c:2884: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_crop’

_imaging.c:2885: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_expand’

_imaging.c:2886: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_filter’

_imaging.c:2887: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_histogram’

_imaging.c:2889: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_modefilter’

_imaging.c:2891: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_offset’

_imaging.c:2892: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_paste’

_imaging.c:2893: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_point’

_imaging.c:2894: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_point_transform’

_imaging.c:2895: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_putdata’

_imaging.c:2897: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_quantize’

_imaging.c:2900: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_rankfilter’

_imaging.c:2902: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_resize’

_imaging.c:2903: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_rotate’

_imaging.c:2904: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_stretch’

_imaging.c:2905: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_transpose’

_imaging.c:2906: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_transform2’

_imaging.c:2908: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_isblock’

_imaging.c:2910: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_getbbox’

_imaging.c:2911: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_getcolors’

_imaging.c:2912: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_getextrema’

_imaging.c:2913: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_getprojection’

_imaging.c:2915: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_getband’

_imaging.c:2916: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_putband’

_imaging.c:2917: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_fillband’

_imaging.c:2919: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘im_setmode’

_imaging.c:2921: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_getpalette’

_imaging.c:2922: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_putpalette’

_imaging.c:2923: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_putpalettealpha’

_imaging.c:2927: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_chop_invert’

_imaging.c:2928: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_chop_lighter’

_imaging.c:2929: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_chop_darker’

_imaging.c:2930: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_chop_difference’

_imaging.c:2931: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_chop_multiply’

_imaging.c:2932: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_chop_screen’

_imaging.c:2933: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_chop_add’

_imaging.c:2934: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_chop_subtract’

_imaging.c:2935: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_chop_add_modulo’

_imaging.c:2936: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_chop_subtract_modulo’

_imaging.c:2937: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_chop_and’

_imaging.c:2938: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_chop_or’

_imaging.c:2939: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_chop_xor’

_imaging.c:2944: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_gaussian_blur’

_imaging.c:2945: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_unsharp_mask’

_imaging.c:2950: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_effect_spread’

_imaging.c:2954: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_new_array’

_imaging.c:2955: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_new_block’

_imaging.c:2958: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘_save_ppm’

_imaging.c:2967: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c: In function ‘image_length’:

_imaging.c:2996: error: ‘ImagingObject’ has no member named ‘image’

_imaging.c: At top level:

_imaging.c:3001: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:3016: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘image_as_sequence’

_imaging.c:3029: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘PyTypeObject’

_imaging.c:3050: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘PyTypeObject’

_imaging.c:3062: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘PyTypeObject’

_imaging.c:3076: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘pixel_access_as_mapping’

_imaging.c:3084: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘PyTypeObject’

_imaging.c:3106: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:3107: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:3108: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:3109: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:3110: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:3111: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:3112: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:3113: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:3114: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:3115: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:3116: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:3117: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:3118: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:3119: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:3120: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:3123: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:3124: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:3125: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:3126: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:3127: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:3128: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:3129: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:3144: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:3147: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:3149: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:3150: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token

_imaging.c:3152: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘functions’

_imaging.c:3250: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’

_imaging.c: In function ‘DL_EXPORT’:

_imaging.c:3250: error: expected declaration specifiers before ‘init_imaging’

_imaging.c:3281: error: expected ‘{’ at end of input

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Comment: "inside my virtualenv I get a gcc error." - and which error exactly?

Comment: What Burhan Khalid says is correct. You might also want to have a look at [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435016/install-pil-on-virtualenv-with-libjpeg), since it is a problem I came across a couple of times.

Comment: How did you install Python2.7? Seems the system cannot find the Python build headers.

Comment: Well you need to figure out where the Python headers are, if you installed from some `.deb` then you will have to download the source manually.

Comment: Can you point me in the correct direction? Which source would I have to download? Python 2.7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you Burhan Khalid for your pointers, they sent me on the way.

What I needed to do was

`sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev.`

That added Python.h to usr/include/python2.7, and gcc was then able to compile PIL.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To install PIL in a virtual environment, first you need to make sure all the dependencies are available on your system.

First, make sure your build environment is installed. Run `sudo apt-get install build-essential`, then run this command:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-imaging
```

Once that is done (it may take some time), activate your virtual environment *without using sudo* and then agin *without using sudo* run `pip install PIL` inside your virtual environment.

When you did `sudo pip install PIL` this installed it in the system-wide Python, and not in your virtual environment.

Comment: I did the sudo apt-get build-dep python-imaging. I did take time, but was successful. However, I still get the same error when I run pip install PIL!

Comment: Paste the complete error, all lines above it and below it. Did you already install `build-essential`?

Comment: Yes, build-essential is installed.

Comment: How can I 'help' it find the python headers?

Answer (score 2):

[This is the guide](https://darrenma.wordpress.com/2012/07/13/installing-pil-into-a-virtualenv-properly-in-ubuntu/) I use, when installing in a new machine:

Dependecies required:

- libjpeg8
- libjpeg8-dev
- libfreetype6
- libfreetype6-dev
- zlib1g
- zlib1g-dev

And double check the symlinks

HTH

Comment: thank you for your time. This is a valuable guide, although it didn't answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

You may have better luck with [Pillow](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow).  Pillow is a fork of PIL which addresses the setuptools incompatibility of PIL.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I already tried this - but got similar error.