# PIL and jpeg decoder not available errors on mac 10.8.2

Tags: python, jpeg, python-imaging-library

I had PIL installed on osx using pip, but since getting the error that jpeg decoder is not available, I uninstalled PIL so that I can first install the jpeg libraries, and then reinstall PIL. However, both the following give me errors:

```
    sudo pip install libjpeg
```

..Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement libjpeg

```
    sudo pip install libjpeg-dev
```

Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement libjpeg-dev

Any ideas how to install the jpeg lib? Thanks.
-TM

Comment: I pressume you've tried all the standard `apt-get update` stuff before running this?

Comment: not sure what apt-get is, but see my comments below to the answer. I have gotten so far with this.

Comment: apt-get is a way to install things on many *nix systems. makes this kind of thing really easy. Don't know if it's available for mac though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a mac, but a quick google search yielded these instructions:

```
$ curl -O http://www.ijg.org/files/jpegsrc.v8c.tar.gz
$ tar zxvf jpegsrc.v8c.tar.gz
$ cd jpeg-8c/
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

at [this](http://arcoleo.org/dsawiki/Wiki.jsp?page=How%20to%20Install%20Libjpeg%20on%20Mac) page.

If that doesn't work, then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8408212/432913) answer to the same question worked for someone, and they got it from [this](http://jetfar.com/libjpeg-and-python-imaging-pil-on-snow-leopard/) blog comment.

Comment: I have just downloaded the jpegsrc v9 file from the url above. I'd now like to know how to install it using pip, and also if I need to first uninstall PIL, install this jpeg library, and then reinstall PIL.

Comment: @user818190 `libjpeg` isn't a python library, you don't install it via pip/easy_install. You install it as a library for the whole computer, and then in then install pil. If it still can't find it, then do what it says in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7528988/432913) answer.

Comment: Ok, so I downloaded the jpegsrc v9 library to my Desktop, installed it as you describe above, and then reinstalled PIL using pip. I got a confirmation that PIL was successfully installed with JPEG support. However, when I use scrapy to crawl a page, I get the same old error: decoder jpeg not available.

Comment: Well i don't know anything about scrapy, i've never used it sorry. you could try what's mentioned here: http://effbot.org/zone/pil-decoder-jpeg-not-available.htm