# Error for pip install Pillow on Ubuntu virtualenv

Tags: ubuntu, pip, virtualenv, python-imaging-library

I have an ec2 instance and had Pillow 2.0 installed in my virtualenv initially.
Somehow when I tried to upgrade it to Pillow 2.5, it failed with the following message. The error is the same even after I removed Pillow completely prior to reinstall. (So now I don't have Pillow in my virtualenv at all)

```
$ pip install Pillow
....
....
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/home/andycheng/realprice/env/build/pillow/libImaging -I/home/andycheng/realprice/env/include -I/usr/include/tcl8.5 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -c libImaging/RawDecode.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/RawDecode.o

gcc: error: unrecognized option ‘-Qunused-arguments’

gcc: error: unrecognized option ‘-Qunused-arguments’

....
....
gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/XbmEncode.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/ZipDecode.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/ZipEncode.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/TiffDecode.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Incremental.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Jpeg2KDecode.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Jpeg2KEncode.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: unrecognized option ‘-Qunused-arguments’

gcc: error: unrecognized option ‘-Qunused-arguments’

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /home/andycheng/realprice/env/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/home/andycheng/realprice/env/build/Pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-U8jA_X-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/andycheng/realprice/env/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /home/andycheng/realprice/env/build/Pillow
```

I don't know if this is related but there are a lot of `gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_imaging.o: No such file or directory` errors in the log. And there are a lot of `gcc: error: unrecognized option ‘-Qunused-arguments’` too.

I am able to install Pillow 2.5 with my root access though, but then the it will not be installed in my virtualenv.

```
sudo pip install Pillow  # this works but wrong directory
pip install -I Pillow==2.0  # gives the same error and would not install
```

Versions

PIP: 1.5.4

Linux: Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS (all package upgraded)

Thank you

Comment: do you have python-dev installed(command: sudo apt-get install python-dev) ?

Comment: yes, I have python-dev installed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally I have found the answer to this headache!

It turns out I have two flag settings in my `.bashrc`:

```
export CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments                                    
export CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
```

The .bashrc was copied from my Macbook Pro and these two flags were required as a work around for XCODE. It seems that they will break in Linux.

After removing these two flags, `pip install Pillow` works as expected.

Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! This was such an obscure error for me. I moved from a Mac to Ubuntu, and some of the packages I was installing (namely virtualenvburrito) were largely geared towards mac users, so I believe they inserted these flags into my environment somehow. To fix it, I added the following two lines to my .bashrc:  
`export CFLAGS=''
export CPPFLAGS=''`

Answer (score 93):

My case was slightly different as my ubuntu 15.04 was missing also libjpeg, so the installation failed each time. Apparently sometimes pillow can not find required library and the easiest way to fix it is to install the dev version and link it to the user libs. Edit: also works in ubuntu 16.04

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo apt-get install libjpeg8-dev
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so /usr/lib

pip install pillow
```

---

Partial solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11708225/3699690)

Comment: I installed `libjpeg-dev`, which pulled `libjpeg62-turbo-dev` on my raspberry pi (Raspbian Jessie). This works with Pillow 3.1.0.

Comment: If you are using python3, then be sure to `sudo apt-get install python3-dev` (remember the 3)

Comment: <sudo apt-get install libjpeg8-dev> did solve the pip install issue for me as well on raspberry pi (Jessie Version 8)

Comment: Awesome. Works like a charm in Raspbian

Comment: for Debian 10, py3.9 this helped me: `sudo apt-get install python3-dev libjpeg-dev`

Answer (score 40):

Note for myself and any others, getting this to compile on Elementary OS Luna (Ubuntu 12.04) requires installation of the python headers you need for your virtualenv python version per the comments on the OP.  I am using the default python version and testing 3.4 (via deadsnakes ppa) so for me this was:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo apt-get install python3.4-dev
```

BUT!  I was still getting the same error!  I checked my .bashrc per the OPs answer, I didn't have any matching exports.  Then it hit me, I'd been troubleshooting for a while and from an answer somewhere else I had tried setting those and hadn't restarted bash.

So don't forget to restart (or re-source I suppose) bash to make sure your exports match .bashrc!

edit: This is a bit long for a comment but not really an answer.  Will modify if necessary.

Comment: This is fine as an answer! `sudo apt-get install python-dev` fixed the problem on my Ubuntu 12.04 box. No other steps needed. (It's a local VirtualBox though, not really an Amazon EC2 image.)

Comment: In many of these cases, installing the `python-dev` package for the specific version of Python you are using in your `virtenv` is the key... For me, v3.3 for this project, worked: `sudo apt-get install python3.3-dev` ... +1

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python3.5-dev` worked on ubuntu16.10 (gnome).

Comment: sudo apt-get install python3.4-dev works on ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 26):

I had the same headache too...

The solution was found after reading docs, that says:

**Starting from version 3.0.0 Pillow needs libjpeg...**

So try the previous one:

```
pip install pillow==2.9.0
```

(It works for python 2.6 and above)

Good Luck!

Comment: Does not seem to work with Python 3.4, Linux 3.13.0-147

Answer (score 11):

The new version 3.0 doesn't work, we need to install the 2.9.0 version which works with Django. Do this while inside the virtual environment:

```
pip install Pillow==2.9.0
```

This should work also in Ubuntu, I use Elementary OS.

Comment: I tried installing libjpeg8-dev per Mr.Coffee's answer; didn't work. Tried installing python3.4-dev; didn't work. Using version 2.9 worked.

Comment: I was too facing the same problem.....With your solution i was able to install pillow....Thanks mate.

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu 16.04 **virtualenv**

```
pip install pillow==2.9.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You might need to install the python development headers.

```
sudo apt-get install build-dep python-imaging
```

Answer (score 0):

On Fedora, installing `rpm-build` solved it for me. Make sure you have `python-devel` and `libjpeg-devel` installed too.

Answer (score 0):

On my CentOS machine I had to:

```
yum install python-devel
```