# Error with a python module installation

Tags: python, gcc, module

I have been trying to install banyan python modules to run python scripts.

I thought that it can be easily installed by using python command "pip install banyan"

However, I got error messages against my expectation. My gcc version is 4.4.7 and python 2.6.

and below large sentences are my error log files.

Can you give me suggestions how to fix my problems? I have already read the related previously posts

but I cannot solve it and every required modules is already installed with latest versions.

and never mind "gcc: unrecognized option '-Qunused-arguments'. It doesn't matter to my problem.

```
    /usr/bin/pip run on Wed Oct 15 22:54:27 2014

Downloading/unpacking banyan

  Running setup.py egg_info for package banyan

    running egg_info
    writing pip-egg-info/Banyan.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/Banyan.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/Banyan.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found
    reading manifest file 'pip-egg-info/Banyan.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/Banyan.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  Source in /tmp/pip-build-sclee1/banyan has version 0.1.5, which satisfies requirement banyan
Installing collected packages: banyan

  Running setup.py install for banyan

    Running command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-sclee1/banyan/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-CZTp63-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    running build_ext
    building 'banyan_c' extension

    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -Ibanyan -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c banyan/module.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/banyan/module.o

    gcc: unrecognized option '-Qunused-arguments'

    gcc: unrecognized option '-Qunused-arguments'

    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -Ibanyan -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c banyan/set_tree.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/banyan/set_tree.o

    gcc: unrecognized option '-Qunused-arguments'

    gcc: unrecognized option '-Qunused-arguments'

    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -Ibanyan -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c banyan/min_gap_metadata.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/banyan/min_gap_metadata.o

    gcc: unrecognized option '-Qunused-arguments'

    gcc: unrecognized option '-Qunused-arguments'

    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -Ibanyan -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c banyan/frozen_set_tree.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/banyan/frozen_set_tree.o

    gcc: unrecognized option '-Qunused-arguments'

    gcc: unrecognized option '-Qunused-arguments'

    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -Ibanyan -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c banyan/tree.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/banyan/tree.o

    gcc: unrecognized option '-Qunused-arguments'

    gcc: unrecognized option '-Qunused-arguments'

    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -Ibanyan -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c banyan/rank_metadata.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/banyan/rank_metadata.o

    gcc: unrecognized option '-Qunused-arguments'

    gcc: unrecognized option '-Qunused-arguments'

    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -Ibanyan -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c banyan/node.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/banyan/node.o

    gcc: unrecognized option '-Qunused-arguments'

    gcc: unrecognized option '-Qunused-arguments'

    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -Ibanyan -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c banyan/frozen_dict_tree.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/banyan/frozen_dict_tree.o

    gcc: unrecognized option '-Qunused-arguments'

    gcc: unrecognized option '-Qunused-arguments'

    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -Ibanyan -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c banyan/dict_tree.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/banyan/dict_tree.o

    gcc: unrecognized option '-Qunused-arguments'

    gcc: unrecognized option '-Qunused-arguments'

    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -Ibanyan -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c banyan/tree_view.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/banyan/tree_view.o

    gcc: unrecognized option '-Qunused-arguments'

    gcc: unrecognized option '-Qunused-arguments'

    banyan/tree_view.cpp: In function ‘void tree_view_dealloc(TreeView*)’:

    banyan/tree_view.cpp:37: warning: suggest explicit braces to avoid ambiguous ‘else’

    banyan/tree_view.cpp:39: warning: suggest explicit braces to avoid ambiguous ‘else’

    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -Ibanyan -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c banyan/overlapping_intervals_metadata.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/banyan/overlapping_intervals_metadata.o

    gcc: unrecognized option '-Qunused-arguments'

    gcc: unrecognized option '-Qunused-arguments'

    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -Ibanyan -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c banyan/_int_imp/_pyobject_utils.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/banyan/_int_imp/_pyobject_utils.o

    gcc: unrecognized option '-Qunused-arguments'

    gcc: unrecognized option '-Qunused-arguments'

    banyan/_int_imp/_pyobject_utils.cpp: In destructor ‘_CachedKeyPyObject::~_CachedKeyPyObject()’:

    banyan/_int_imp/_pyobject_utils.cpp:416: warning: suggest explicit braces to avoid ambiguous ‘else’

    banyan/_int_imp/_pyobject_utils.cpp:418: warning: suggest explicit braces to avoid ambiguous ‘else’

    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -Ibanyan -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c banyan/_int_imp/_build_tree_imp.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/banyan/_int_imp/_build_tree_imp.o

    gcc: unrecognized option '-Qunused-arguments'

    gcc: unrecognized option '-Qunused-arguments'

    In file included from banyan/_int_imp/_tree_imp_metadata_base.hpp:14,

                     from banyan/_int_imp/_tree_imp_lt_base.hpp:6,

                     from banyan/_int_imp/_tree_imp.hpp:7,

                     from banyan/_int_imp/_set_tree_imp.hpp:7,

                     from banyan/_int_imp/_build_tree_imp.cpp:9:

    banyan/_int_imp/_tree_imp_pyobject_cached_key_value_type_set_base.hpp: In constructor ‘_PyObjectCachedKeyUniqueSorterIncer<true>::_PyObjectCachedKeyUniqueSorterIncer(PyObject*, const _CachedKeyPyObjectCacheGeneratorLT&)’:

    banyan/_int_imp/_tree_imp_pyobject_cached_key_value_type_set_base.hpp:33: error: using ‘typename’ outside of template

    banyan/_int_imp/_tree_imp_pyobject_cached_key_value_type_set_base.hpp:35: error: using ‘typename’ outside of template

    In file included from banyan/_int_imp/_tree_imp_lt_base.hpp:10,

                     from banyan/_int_imp/_tree_imp.hpp:7,

                     from banyan/_int_imp/_set_tree_imp.hpp:7,

                     from banyan/_int_imp/_build_tree_imp.cpp:9:

    banyan/_int_imp/_tree_imp_min_gap_metadata_base.hpp: In member function ‘__MinGapMetadata<PyObject*>& __MinGapMetadata<PyObject*>::operator=(const __MinGapMetadata<PyObject*>::ThisT&)’:

    banyan/_int_imp/_tree_imp_min_gap_metadata_base.hpp:195: warning: suggest explicit braces to avoid ambiguous ‘else’



    banyan/_int_imp/_tree_imp_min_gap_metadata_base.hpp: In member function ‘void __MinGapMetadata<PyObject*>::update(PyObject*, const __MinGapMetadata<PyObject*>::ThisT*, const __MinGapMetadata<PyObject*>::ThisT*)’:

    banyan/_int_imp/_tree_imp_min_gap_metadata_base.hpp:206: warning: suggest explicit braces to avoid ambiguous ‘else’

    banyan/_int_imp/_tree_imp_min_gap_metadata_base.hpp:208: warning: suggest explicit braces to avoid ambiguous ‘else’

    banyan/_int_imp/_tree_imp_min_gap_metadata_base.hpp:210: warning: suggest explicit braces to avoid ambiguous ‘else’

    In file included from banyan/_int_imp/_tree_imp_lt_base.hpp:11,

                     from banyan/_int_imp/_tree_imp.hpp:7,

                     from banyan/_int_imp/_set_tree_imp.hpp:7,

                     from banyan/_int_imp/_build_tree_imp.cpp:9:

    banyan/_int_imp/_tree_imp_interval_max_metadata_base.hpp: In member function ‘_PyObjectIntervalMaxMetadata& _PyObjectIntervalMaxMetadata::operator=(const _PyObjectIntervalMaxMetadata&)’:

    banyan/_int_imp/_tree_imp_interval_max_metadata_base.hpp:59: warning: suggest explicit braces to avoid ambiguous ‘else’

    banyan/_int_imp/_tree_imp_interval_max_metadata_base.hpp: In destructor ‘virtual _PyObjectIntervalMaxMetadata::~_PyObjectIntervalMaxMetadata()’:

    banyan/_int_imp/_tree_imp_interval_max_metadata_base.hpp:73: warning: suggest explicit braces to avoid ambiguous ‘else’

    banyan/_int_imp/_tree_imp_interval_max_metadata_base.hpp: In member function ‘void _PyObjectIntervalMaxMetadata::update(PyObject*, const _PyObjectIntervalMaxMetadata*, const _PyObjectIntervalMaxMetadata*)’:

    banyan/_int_imp/_tree_imp_interval_max_metadata_base.hpp:80: warning: suggest explicit braces to avoid ambiguous ‘else’

    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-sclee1/banyan/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-CZTp63-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed:

    running install

running build

running build_py

running build_ext

building 'banyan_c' extension

gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -Ibanyan -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c banyan/module.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/banyan/module.o

gcc: unrecognized option '-Qunused-arguments'

gcc: unrecognized option '-Qunused-arguments'

gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -Ibanyan -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c banyan/set_tree.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/banyan/set_tree.o

gcc: unrecognized option '-Qunused-arguments'

gcc: unrecognized option '-Qunused-arguments'

gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -Ibanyan -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c banyan/min_gap_metadata.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/banyan/min_gap_metadata.o

gcc: unrecognized option '-Qunused-arguments'

gcc: unrecognized option '-Qunused-arguments'

gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -Ibanyan -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c banyan/frozen_set_tree.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/banyan/frozen_set_tree.o

gcc: unrecognized option '-Qunused-arguments'

gcc: unrecognized option '-Qunused-arguments'

gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -Ibanyan -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c banyan/tree.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/banyan/tree.o


gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -Ibanyan -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c banyan/rank_metadata.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/banyan/rank_metadata.o


gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -Ibanyan -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c banyan/node.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/banyan/node.o

gcc: unrecognized option '-Qunused-arguments'

gcc: unrecognized option '-Qunused-arguments'

gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -Ibanyan -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c banyan/frozen_dict_tree.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/banyan/frozen_dict_tree.o

gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -Ibanyan -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c banyan/dict_tree.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/banyan/dict_tree.o

gcc: unrecognized option '-Qunused-arguments'

gcc: unrecognized option '-Qunused-arguments'

gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -Ibanyan -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c banyan/tree_view.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/banyan/tree_view.o

gcc: unrecognized option '-Qunused-arguments'

gcc: unrecognized option '-Qunused-arguments'

banyan/tree_view.cpp: In function ‘void tree_view_dealloc(TreeView*)’:

banyan/tree_view.cpp:37: warning: suggest explicit braces to avoid ambiguous ‘else’

banyan/tree_view.cpp:39: warning: suggest explicit braces to avoid ambiguous ‘else’

gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -Ibanyan -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c banyan/overlapping_intervals_metadata.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/banyan/overlapping_intervals_metadata.o

gcc: unrecognized option '-Qunused-arguments'

gcc: unrecognized option '-Qunused-arguments'

gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -Ibanyan -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c banyan/_int_imp/_pyobject_utils.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/banyan/_int_imp/_pyobject_utils.o

gcc: unrecognized option '-Qunused-arguments'

gcc: unrecognized option '-Qunused-arguments'

banyan/_int_imp/_pyobject_utils.cpp: In destructor ‘_CachedKeyPyObject::~_CachedKeyPyObject()’:

banyan/_int_imp/_pyobject_utils.cpp:416: warning: suggest explicit braces to avoid ambiguous ‘else’

banyan/_int_imp/_pyobject_utils.cpp:418: warning: suggest explicit braces to avoid ambiguous ‘else’

gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -Ibanyan -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c banyan/_int_imp/_build_tree_imp.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/banyan/_int_imp/_build_tree_imp.o

gcc: unrecognized option '-Qunused-arguments'

gcc: unrecognized option '-Qunused-arguments'

In file included from banyan/_int_imp/_tree_imp_metadata_base.hpp:14,

                 from banyan/_int_imp/_tree_imp_lt_base.hpp:6,

                 from banyan/_int_imp/_tree_imp.hpp:7,

                 from banyan/_int_imp/_set_tree_imp.hpp:7,

                 from banyan/_int_imp/_build_tree_imp.cpp:9:

banyan/_int_imp/_tree_imp_pyobject_cached_key_value_type_set_base.hpp: In constructor ‘_PyObjectCachedKeyUniqueSorterIncer<true>::_PyObjectCachedKeyUniqueSorterIncer(PyObject*, const _CachedKeyPyObjectCacheGeneratorLT&)’:

banyan/_int_imp/_tree_imp_pyobject_cached_key_value_type_set_base.hpp:33: error: using ‘typename’ outside of template

banyan/_int_imp/_tree_imp_pyobject_cached_key_value_type_set_base.hpp:35: error: using ‘typename’ outside of template

In file included from banyan/_int_imp/_tree_imp_lt_base.hpp:10,

                 from banyan/_int_imp/_tree_imp.hpp:7,

                 from banyan/_int_imp/_set_tree_imp.hpp:7,

                 from banyan/_int_imp/_build_tree_imp.cpp:9:

banyan/_int_imp/_tree_imp_min_gap_metadata_base.hpp: In member function ‘__MinGapMetadata<PyObject*>& __MinGapMetadata<PyObject*>::operator=(const __MinGapMetadata<PyObject*>::ThisT&)’:

banyan/_int_imp/_tree_imp_min_gap_metadata_base.hpp:175: warning: suggest explicit braces to avoid ambiguous ‘else’

banyan/_int_imp/_tree_imp_min_gap_metadata_base.hpp: In destructor ‘virtual __MinGapMetadata<PyObject*>::~__MinGapMetadata()’:

banyan/_int_imp/_tree_imp_min_gap_metadata_base.hpp:195: warning: suggest explicit braces to avoid ambiguous ‘else’

banyan/_int_imp/_tree_imp_min_gap_metadata_base.hpp:197: warning: suggest explicit braces to avoid ambiguous ‘else’

banyan/_int_imp/_tree_imp_min_gap_metadata_base.hpp:199: warning: suggest explicit braces to avoid ambiguous ‘else’

banyan/_int_imp/_tree_imp_min_gap_metadata_base.hpp: In member function ‘void __MinGapMetadata<PyObject*>::update(PyObject*, const __MinGapMetadata<PyObject*>::ThisT*, const __MinGapMetadata<PyObject*>::ThisT*)’:

banyan/_int_imp/_tree_imp_min_gap_metadata_base.hpp:206: warning: suggest explicit braces to avoid ambiguous ‘else’

banyan/_int_imp/_tree_imp_min_gap_metadata_base.hpp:208: warning: suggest explicit braces to avoid ambiguous ‘else’

banyan/_int_imp/_tree_imp_min_gap_metadata_base.hpp:210: warning: suggest explicit braces to avoid ambiguous ‘else’

In file included from banyan/_int_imp/_tree_imp_lt_base.hpp:11,

                 from banyan/_int_imp/_tree_imp.hpp:7,

                 from banyan/_int_imp/_set_tree_imp.hpp:7,

                 from banyan/_int_imp/_build_tree_imp.cpp:9:

banyan/_int_imp/_tree_imp_interval_max_metadata_base.hpp: In member function ‘_PyObjectIntervalMaxMetadata& _PyObjectIntervalMaxMetadata::operator=(const _PyObjectIntervalMaxMetadata&)’:

banyan/_int_imp/_tree_imp_interval_max_metadata_base.hpp:59: warning: suggest explicit braces to avoid ambiguous ‘else’

banyan/_int_imp/_tree_imp_interval_max_metadata_base.hpp: In destructor ‘virtual _PyObjectIntervalMaxMetadata::~_PyObjectIntervalMaxMetadata()’:

banyan/_int_imp/_tree_imp_interval_max_metadata_base.hpp:73: warning: suggest explicit braces to avoid ambiguous ‘else’

banyan/_int_imp/_tree_imp_interval_max_metadata_base.hpp: In member function ‘void _PyObjectIntervalMaxMetadata::update(PyObject*, const _PyObjectIntervalMaxMetadata*, const _PyObjectIntervalMaxMetadata*)’:

banyan/_int_imp/_tree_imp_interval_max_metadata_base.hpp:80: warning: suggest explicit braces to avoid ambiguous ‘else’

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------

Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-sclee1/banyan/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-CZTp63-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-sclee1/banyan

Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 139, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 271, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1185, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 592, in install
    cwd=self.source_dir, filter_stdout=self._filter_install, show_stdout=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/util.py", line 662, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-sclee1/banyan/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-CZTp63-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-sclee1/banyan
```

Comment: Check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24646305/error-for-pip-install-pillow-on-ubuntu-virtualenv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try installing an executable file from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/. I always use when there is an issue with pip/easy_install