# Error Installing Pillow on OpenSuse

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, opensuse

I tried installing Pillow on OpenSuse but get some error relating to missing libImaging files. I have installed libjpeg, libjpep-turbo, libjpeg8-devel, and python-devel before running:

```
pip install Pillow
```

and still get the same error. Any suggestions what library I might need to install?
Error Message Extract:

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/UnsharpMask.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/XbmDecode.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/XbmEncode.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/ZipDecode.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/ZipEncode.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/TiffDecode.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Incremental.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Jpeg2KDecode.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Jpeg2KEncode.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/BoxBlur.o: No such file or directory
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Comment: Did you try installing inside a virtualenv?

Comment: Take a look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24646305/1165509

Comment: Thanks. Tried the option of installing Pillow==2.9.0 and other tools but still not getting it to work. The command pip list shows that Pillow (2.9.0) has been installed but nothing still works